# ¿Cómo puedo rotar un círculo sobre su propio eje en canvas sin translate()?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Lo que sucede es que al intentar rotar un círculo en el `canvas` con el método  `translate()` el método copea los demás gráficos en el `canvas` y los pega rotados encima de los originales.  (El círculo si se dibuja)

código:

```
/// Esto es el método para crear círculos


    Canvas.prototype.Cir = function(circulo){
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(circulo.x, circulo.y, circulo.r, circulo.sA, circulo.eA);
    this.ctx.translate(circulo.x2, circulo.y2);
    this.ctx.rotate(circulo.rads * Math.PI /180);
    this.ctx.lineWidth = circulo.lW;
    this.ctx.setLineDash([circulo.lL, circulo.sp]);
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = circulo.color;
    this.ctx.stroke();
};


/// En la función dibujar de el código


         pantalla.limpiar();
         /* Demas gráficos*/
        pantalla.Cir(sin);

///info

    sin = {
        x: 250,
        x2: pantalla.canvas.height/2,
        y: 0,
        y2: pantalla.canvas.height/2,
        r: 2,
        rads: -45,
        sA: 0,
        eA: 2*Math.PI,
        lW: 4,
        color: "black",
        lL: 0,
        sp: 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución para tu problema sería seguir utilizando las transformaciones que necesites junto con [los métodos save() y restore()](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/canvas/save-restore.php) del contexto del canvas.

El método `save()` guarda el estado actual del contexto del canvas antes de la transformación. Después de `save()` puedes transformar el contexto, y después de la transformación y de pintar la imagen llamas el método `restore()` que recupera el último estado guardado del contexto, o sea de antes de la transformación.

*Una observación*: en tu código primero dibujas el circulo y después transformas el contexto. Esto dejaría el circulo sin transformar. En mi código lo he cambiado pero es posible que tu tengas tus razones por hacerlo así.

Me habría gustado ver todo el código en un ejemplo funcional. Te habría podido ayudar más. Espero que sea útil.

```js
class Canvas {
  constructor(){
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.w = this.canvas.width = 500;
    this.h = this.canvas.height = 500;
  }
  limpiar(){
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h );
  }
}

/// Esto es el método para crear círculos


Canvas.prototype.Cir = function(circulo){
    this.ctx.save();
  
    this.ctx.translate(circulo.x2, circulo.y2);
    this.ctx.rotate(circulo.rads * Math.PI /180);
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(circulo.x, circulo.y, circulo.r, circulo.sA, circulo.eA);

    this.ctx.lineWidth = circulo.lW;
    this.ctx.setLineDash([circulo.lL, circulo.sp]);
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = circulo.color;
    this.ctx.stroke();
  
    this.ctx.restore();  
};
let pantalla = new Canvas();

///info

    sin = {
        x: 250,
        y: 0,
        r: 2,
        sA: 0,
        eA: 2*Math.PI,
      
        x2: pantalla.h/2,
        y2: pantalla.h/2,
        
        rads: -45,
        
        lW: 4,
        lL: 0,
        sp: 0,
        color: "black",
 
    }




/// En la función dibujar de el código


        pantalla.limpiar();
         /* Demas gráficos*/
        pantalla.Cir(sin);
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```